# PowerShell Modules, can you have the Version update per function?

Tags: powershell, function, module, version

Sorry for the poor title wording. What I'm looking for, if it's possible is, I have my custom module. If I run the command `Get-Command -Module $MyModule` I get my list of functions with a Version tied to it.

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Add-Border                                         1.0.0      $MyModule
Function        ConvertFrom-Base64String                           1.0.0      $MyModule
Function        ConvertFrom-CIDR                                   1.0.0      $MyModule
Function        ConvertTo-Base64String                             1.0.0      $MyModule
```

It seems like that version is tied to my module's manifest file, as if I update that version number, than the versions above reflect that change.

However, is there a way to have just the `Add-Border` have it's own version so if I update just that piece, than that reflects it's version and not the entire manifests versioning?

Ideally, I am going for import a single module `$MyModule` and it either has additional modules nested within, or just `.ps1` files that house functions.
What I'm ultimately shooting for is, if someone is using my module, I can see if they are using the updated version of the function

Comment: The version [comes straight from the module](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/8686612cfe08f58e42acd4b1dc030f8c38c2728a/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandInfo.cs#L195). If you really wanted to, you could add your own noteproperty with a custom version number, but that doesn't really make sense. Your users aren't going to update individual functions inside the module, so the module version number already tells you what version of the function they're on.

Comment: If you're doing good release management you'll be able to track back from the module's version to the commit in source control that it was built from - that will show you the exact definition of every function in the module for that version. If you're releasing updated versions of individual functions to be spliced into the module you're going to get yourself into all sorts of trouble trying to test or troubleshoot live issues - just ship a new version of the whole module instead, or if they *really* need to be versioned independently, put them in different modules and ship them separately.